# remove a specific column from many dataframes stored in a list

Tags: r

I have a piece of code that is reading in many dataframes and then rbinding them

```
data.files = paths %>% ##takes the names of all the objects that I want to read in
  map(read.csv) %>% ##this reads all the correctly named .csv files into a list object
  reduce(rbind) ##reduces them all from the list into a single dataframe by rbind
```

where `paths` is a vector of names of .csv files to be read in. However the problem is that many of these objects are missing a single column `LaserEnergy` which makes the rbind fail. This column is not important to my analysis and is a leftover of earlier data processing. Is there a way that I can go through and either remove the column from each object in the list that has that column or else add an empty column in the correct position to those that don't have it?

The alternative is my going through over 2000 files and either adding or removing the column manually.

Comment: Add a pipe with `select(-LaserEnergy)` before your `reduce(rbind)` call?

Answer (score 6):

Something like this? Without examples of data it's hard to tell what will work exactly, but using `purrr::map_dfr` which is shorthand for `map` then `bind_rows` should avoid an error. `bind_rows` will not throw an error if columns are not present in all list elements, it just fills with `NA`. You can then drop the unwanted column from your resulting dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)
data.files <- paths %>%
    map_dfr(read_csv) %>%
    select(-LaserEnergy)
```

Comment: That throws an error that one of the columns can't be converted from character to integer (it shouldn't be an integer column). I read the documentation for `bind_rows`  and `read_csv` and nothing jumped out at me to address the issue. is there an argument I can apply that tells it to leave columns as is?

Comment: `col_types` is how you specify the column types, `cols` is how you change the default. Because you have different column numbers you could just set default to character and fix afterwards. Again, this is the kind of problem that cannot be mind-read and needs an example to fix. Glad you got something working though.

Answer (score 1):

This is what ended up working for me, I had to use the `data.table` package as well

```
data.files <- paths %>%
   map(read._csv) %>%
   rbindlist(fill = T)  ##This function is from the data.tables package, fill = T tells it to fill missing columns with NA
```

For some reason, `read_csv` did not like the column classes when used in conjunction with `map_dfr()` and was trying to force columns into classes they shouldn't have been. I couldn't find anything in the documentation that would address it (trying to specify `col_types` didn't work for me